# How to say "Every five days" in French?

Tags: indications-de-temps, formulation-idiomatique

Which one would a native speaker say (most preferably)

My attempt: *Toutes les journée cinq.*

Google Translate : *Tous le cinq jours.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Tous les cinq jours" is correct

Answer (score 8):

The correct translation is **`Tous les cinq jours`**.

**Explanation :**

Every : `Tous` for masculine plural or `Toutes` for feminine plural.

Five days : `cinq jours`.

Since `jour` (day in French) is a masculine word, then the equivalent will be **`Tous`** and not `Toutes`.

So till now, we get `Tous` + `cinq jours`. This is incomplete because the word `jours` should be preceeded by an `article` : `les` (masculine plural).

Finally : **`Tous les cinq jours`**

***One more thing*** : `jour` vs. `journée` :

`journée` (feminine word) is used to highlight that part of the day or this day in its **duration**, when you want to emphasise the **length of time**.

`jour` (masculine word) is used to highlight this time of the day or the day as a **precise moment**, a **time unit** in which an action took place.

Answer (score 3):

"Tous les cinq jours" convient.